# Multiple queries with Xquery

Tags: xml, xquery, basex

I just ran this xquery and it works just fine

```
<usp>{count(for $e in doc("yyyyyy.xml")/Games/Game/Event

where $e/@player_id = 14937
  and $e/@type_id = 1
  and $e/@outcome = 0

let $c := count($e[Q[@qualifier_id = "2"]])
return if($c<1)
      then $e/@event_id
      else ())}</usp>
```

However, no I would like to run this query for $e/@outcome = 1 too. How can I do this? I would like to avoid making a new xquery for it.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can define external variables in XQuery, e.g. like so:

```
declare variable $outcome external := 0;
<usp>{count(for $e in doc("yyyyyy.xml")/Games/Game/Event

where $e/@player_id = 14937
  and $e/@type_id = 1
  and $e/@outcome = 0

let $c := count($e[Q[@qualifier_id = "2"]])
return if($c<1)
      then $e/@event_id
      else ())}</usp>
```

If you call basex from standalone, you can bind to the external `$outcome` variable by using `-b`

```
basex -b outcome=1 <xquery_file>
```

Comment: Great, any info on how to call basex from standalone (which standalone to use)? How does the system know where to go and look for the xquery file? I guess <xquery_file> must be replaced by <actual xquery file name>? Thanks for your help!

Comment: You execute BaseX like you execute any other program with your specific operating system. Please take a look at our documentation at http://docs.basex.org/wiki/Main_Page to answer your basic questions.

Answer (score 0):

This will run the query for where the outcome is `0` or `1`:

```
<usp>{
    count(
      for $e in doc("yyyyyy.xml")/Games/Game/Event[@player_id eq 14937][@type_id eq 1][@outcome = (0, 1)]
      let $c := count($e[Q/@qualifier_id eq "2"])
      return
        if($c<1)then
          $e/@event_id
        else
          ()
    )
}</usp>
```

I think your `let/return/if` statement is somewhat misleading though as it will always have a count of 1 because you are iterating a tuple stream.

Comment: Hi, thanks you so much for your answer. It's interesting, but not exactly what I hoped for. The return is now 55 which is the sum of outcome=1 (44) and outcome=0 (11). Any idea how is possible to see both of them seperately instead of the sum? 

Thanks in advance
P.S.: What is a tuple stream?

Answer (score 0):

Slightly different interpretation on your request as it is unclear if you want the answers separately(by way of a variable) or in the same result:

```
let $game := 
<game>
  <event player_id="14937" type_id="1" outcome="0" event_id="1" qualifier_id="2"/>
  <event player_id="14937" type_id="1" outcome="1" event_id="1" qualifier_id="2"/>
  <event player_id="14937" type_id="1" outcome="1" event_id="1" qualifier_id="2"/>
  <event player_id="14937" type_id="1" outcome="1" event_id="1" qualifier_id="2"/>
  <event player_id="14999" type_id="1" outcome="2" event_id="1" qualifier_id="2"/>
</game>


let $matching-results := for $e in $game/event
    where $e/@player_id = 14937
      and $e/@type_id = 1
      and $e/@qualifier_id = 2
  return $e

return <usp>
      {
      for $outcome-type in fn:distinct-values($matching-results/@outcome)
        let $outcome-count := fn:count($matching-results[@outcome=$outcome-type])
        return <outcome type="{$outcome-type}">{$outcome-count}</outcome>
      }
</usp>
```

Results:

```
<usp>
    <outcome type="0">1</outcome>
    <outcome type="1">3</outcome>
</usp>
```

I first got the candidate results before creating my list of outcome possibilities (0 and 1) and not additional values that may be found in other records and not match here.  This is why there is no outcome type="2" even though I seeded the data with one for a test (player ending in 999)